# Как в SQL отфильтровать строки, которые состоят из 3 букв?

Tags: sql, access

> Условие: Напишите запрос для получения списка студентов, фамилии которых состоят из 3 букв.

```
SELECT Surname, Name FROM Student WHERE Surname LIKE '___';
```

Почему запрос не работает и можно ли его написать по другому?

Comment: Поставьте флажок "Стандарт SQL-92" в настройках Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

> _ - The underscore represents a single character
>
> Note: MS Access uses a question mark (?) instead of the underscore (_).

```
SELECT Surname, Name FROM Student WHERE Surname LIKE '???';
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_len.asp

```
SELECT Surname, Name FROM Student WHERE Len(Surname) = 3;
```